# KieBase has no KiePackage when created from a kieContainer

Tags: java, drools, jbpm, kie

I have created a kieBase and I am not finding any kiePackage inside it. The Syso statement prints an empty list.

```
kFile.write("D:/Test Rule/simple.drl",kieService.getResources().newReaderResource( new StringReader(new String(drlRuleData)) ));
    kiebuilder = kieService.newKieBuilder(kFile).buildAll();
                if (kiebuilder.getResults().hasMessages(Message.Level.ERROR)) {
                    logger.error("kiebuilder has errors", kiebuilder.getResults().getMessages(Message.Level.ERROR));
                    throw new CEHServiceException("Errors in drl file for Alert Classification",
                            kiebuilder.getResults().getMessages(Message.Level.ERROR).toString());
                }
                kieContainer = kieService.newKieContainer(kbuilder.getKieModule().getReleaseId());
                kieBase= kContainer.getKieBase();
System.out.println("The packages are : "+kbaseAcknowledgement.getKiePackages().toString());
```

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think that Windows-style paths are a good idea. Use `src/main/resources/simple.drl` instead. If you suspect that there are no packages, use a DRL text with some errors in it and check whether the looger shows error messages.

Comment: I tried entering a wrong drl and it showed me errors.. But I can clearly see that the default kieBase in the KieContainer does not contain any package in it..

Comment: And I have tried with this src/main/resources/simple.drl path also.. no difference.. And there are no problems with the KieFileSystem.. I could see my drl being written in the KieFileSystem..